# Jekyll not serving locally - 'could not find jekyll'

Tags: ruby, rubygems, jekyll

I have little-to-no experience with ruby, but have been managing to successfully maintain a Jekyll site with github. However, for some unknown reason, when I cd into my website's directory and run `jekyll serve` I get the following error:

`Could not find 'jekyll' (>= 0) among 7 total gem(s) (Gem::MissingSpecError)`

Here is the full error message:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.4.1_1/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:308:in `to_specs': Could not find 'jekyll' (>= 0) among 7 total gem(s) (Gem::MissingSpecError)
Checked in 'GEM_PATH=/Users/amin/.gem/ruby/2.4.0:/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0:/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.4.1_1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0', execute `gem env` for more information
from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.4.1_1/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:320:in `to_spec'
from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.4.1_1/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:65:in `gem'
from /usr/local/bin/jekyll:22:in `<main>'
```

Trying `gem env` gives this, which looks a little messy:

```
RubyGems Environment:
 - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.4.5
 - RUBY VERSION: 2.2.2 (2015-04-13 patchlevel 95) [x86_64-darwin15]
 - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0
 - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/local/opt/ruby/bin/ruby
 - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/local/bin
 - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /Users/amin/.gem/specs
 - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.2.2/etc
 - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
   - ruby
   - x86_64-darwin-15
 - GEM PATHS:
   - /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0
   - /Users/amin/.gem/ruby/2.2.0
   - /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0
 - GEM CONFIGURATION:
   - :update_sources => true
   - :verbose => true
   - :backtrace => false
   - :bulk_threshold => 1000
 - REMOTE SOURCES:
   - https://rubygems.org/
 - SHELL PATH:
   - /Users/amin/Dropbox/code/google-cloud-platform/google-cloud-sdk/bin
   - //anaconda/bin
   - /opt/local/bin
   - /opt/local/sbin
   - /opt/local/bin
   - /opt/local/sbin
   - /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin
   - /usr/local/bin
   - /usr/bin
   - /bin
   - /usr/sbin
   - /sbin
   - /opt/X11/bin
   - /Library/TeX/texbin
```

My best guess is that Jekyll should be looking in `usr/local/bin`, and not `usr/local/Cellar`, but as I say, that's just a guess.

Any advice on how to get this working again would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you use `bundler` to manage your gems? Have you run `bundle` inside your Jekyll root folder? Have you tried running `bundle exec jekyll serve`?

Comment: `Cellar` is used by `Homebrew`. Perhaps try reinstall `jekyll` with `RubyGems`?